# How to find a specific BBC debate or podcast using Alexa and TuneIn?

Tags: smart-home, alexa, amazon-echo, communication, web-services

Kinda silly, but looking at:

> This show will be available later. Please come back then.

https://tunein.com/radio/Intelligence-Squared-Debate-p510948/

Is there a podcast for the BBC [debates](https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/n13xtmdd) available through Alexa using the default TuneIn app?

The US debates are [readily](https://tunein.com/podcasts/News--Politics-Podcasts/Intelligence-Squared-US-Debates-p1139728/) available; not sure how to get the BBC episodes.  (Yes, I have the [anypod](https://anypod.net/) skill enabled on Alexa.)